# Run a Job on EC2 from a (python) lambda

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

When a file is placed in S3 a Lambda function is triggered which intern should trigger a job in EC2 instance. what is the best approach to get access EC2 access from Lambda and run the job?

Comment: What do you mean "a job"?  What do you have installed on the EC2 - a web server perhaps?    How can an external process run the job?

Answer (score 1):

- This is a python lambda code which looks for an ec2 instance with tag `Environment:Dev`.
- aws [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/scheduling-ssh-jobs-using-aws-lambda/)
- S3 trigger a lambda using terraform [github](https://github.com/amittn/s3-trigger-lambda)

```
import boto3

def trigger_handler(event, context):
    #Get IP addresses of EC2 instances
    client = boto3.client('ec2')
    instDict=client.describe_instances(
            Filters=[{'Name':'tag:Environment','Values':['Dev']}]
        )

    hostList=[]
    for r in instDict['Reservations']:
        for inst in r['Instances']:
            hostList.append(inst['PublicIpAddress'])

    #Invoke worker function for each IP address
    client = boto3.client('lambda')
    for host in hostList:
        print "Invoking worker_function on " + host
        invokeResponse=client.invoke(
            FunctionName='worker_function',
            InvocationType='Event',
            LogType='Tail',
            Payload='{"IP":"'+ host +'"}'
        )
        print invokeResponse

    return{
        'message' : "Trigger function finished"
    }
```